# Setting up Mercurial for members of a unix group

Tags: bash, unix, mercurial

I have a Mercurial repository set up on a Linux server, and some (but not all) users have permission to push to it. They connect to the repository over ssh.

These users are members of a unix group together. Below is the script I'm using to alter a repository to allow it to receive pushes from them.

Can this be improved? Are there unnecessary operations in here? Is anything bad style for a `bash` script?

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
    echo Usage: $0 directory groupname
    exit 1
fi

if ! chown -R :$2 $1; then
    echo chown failure
    exit 2
fi

if ! find $1/.hg -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;; then
    echo chmod failure
    exit 3
fi

if ! find $1 -perm -u+r -exec chmod g+r {} \;; then
    echo chmod failure 2
    exit 4
fi

if ! find $1 -perm -u+w -exec chmod g+w {} \;; then
    echo chmod failure 3
    exit 5
fi

if ! find $1 -perm -u+x -exec chmod g+x {} \;; then
    echo chmod failure 4
    exit 6
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running find with -exec launches a separate chown process for each file.  You'll get a lot less process thrash (and more speed) if you do:

```
find "$1"/.hg -type d -print0 | xargs chmod g+s
find "$1" -perm -u+r -print0 | xargs chmod g+r
find "$1" -perm -u+w -print0 | xargs chmod g+w
find "$1" -perm -u+x -print0 | xargs chmod g+x
```

As an aside, have you looked at Mercurial's [ACL Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension) in combination with [hg-ssh](http://www.selenic.com/repo/hg-stable/raw-file/tip/contrib/hg-ssh)?  So long as the only access is ssh, it does the same sort of thing.

Comment: Newer GNU finds (they implemented it relatively late, it's in POSIX since ages...) know "-exec .... {} +", which will spawn the process using as many arguments as fit into the environment space, effectively doing what xargs would do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ACL Extension. Another option I found from your links was mercurial-server (http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SharedSSH). I think I'll stick with my script for now, though, with John, TheBonsai, and your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Couple minor things: It's a good idea to echo error messages to stderr by redirecting with `>&2`. And you should add double quotes around variables so your script will work with file names that have spaces.

You could change the initial line to `#!/bin/bash -e` to have the script immediately exit if there's an error. That'd let you remove all the `if` statements. Or if you want more control you could use the `trap ERR` command to call custom error-handling code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function uhoh() {
    echo "error in script!" >&2
    exit 1
}

trap uhoh ERR

if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 directory groupname" >&2
    exit 1
fi

chown -R :"$2" "$1"
find "$1"/.hg -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
find "$1" -perm -u+r -exec chmod g+r {} \;
find "$1" -perm -u+w -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find "$1" -perm -u+x -exec chmod g+x {} \;
```

Personally I'd just go with the `/bin/bash -e` option if you want to stop the script as soon as something fails. I think checking the result of every command and having a different exit code for each one is overkill. You don't need to be that robust, and nobody's gonna be doing anything different for exit code 3 vs. exit code 4...